# Is Working as a Programmer in a Poker Game Company Haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Recently, I have accepted an offer to work as a programmer at a Poker Game company. The work that I do does not directly involve promoting the poker game. I am just providing a service to the company where I develop software for them according to their requirements.

The main reason I have accepted the offer at this company is because the job matches my current skills and the pay is good. I couldn't find any similar jobs at other companies where the pay is as good as in this company. The pay is really important for me as I am saving up to get married in less than a year.

Therefore, I would like to know, considering my situation, is it haram to work in this company? What should I do? Thank you.